# Using python to get web pages containing JavaScript

Tags: python, web-applications

I am new to python. As part of writing a module to scrape URLs I noticed that what I get using the python requests module could be different from what I get if I load the URL in a browser. This is because the page could contain JS code which is executed and the result is hat I see in the browser.

My questions - 
1. how do I deal with such sites.

1. Is python or any other module limited to just getting static pages or pages completely rendered on the server side?
2. How to deal with pages that do an Ajax style queries to load pages?

I am assuming that there probably isn't a library for this and I have to do something on my own. I hope I don't have to build in something like webkit into my code :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into something that either simulates a browser, like [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.2.5), or actually drives a browser, like [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.31.0), which should report the html you see after the javascript runs.

This should be what you need to do with Selenium, but it's been a while:

```
from selenium import webdriver

br = WebDriver.Ie() #or .Firefox() or .Chrome() (but not on x64)
br.get(r'http://google.com')
html = br.page_source
```

for html comparison, it's at least different:

```
from requests import get
r = get(r'http://google.com')
print r.content[:100]
>>><!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta itemprop'
print html[:100]
>>><html itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="itemscope"><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compat
```

Comment: Does selenium provide an API to get the web page source after its rendered in the engine?

Comment: Isn't that what `page_source` is? Maybe it's before it's treated with js, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

- http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/
- http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/

and a related question: [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Comment: Its not clear to me how having a javascript engine will help me. I need the DOM + JS + HTML interaction and rendering for the web page right? If so I would need something that simulates the browser. Am I wrong?